# .text field for label not working

Tags: asp.net, label

I have a custom control that generates a label-input pair for a form. I want that label's text to be controlled by the name field instead of the ID field. However, when I go into the custom control and explicitly set my label's text field equal to the name, the label's text is always the ID of my custom control. Why?

Form on page:

```
<FormUpgrade:FormUpgrade ID="fname" type="text" name="First Name" runat="server" />
```

In my `oninit` function, I have the lines:

```
aLabel.Text = name;
this.Controls.Add(this.aLabel);
```

`aLabel` is never touched after that.

However, if I type my label field manually, then the Text field behaves as expected.

Here's the code for the whole custom control:

```
namespace FormUpgrade
{
    [DefaultProperty("Text")]
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:FormUpgrade runat=server></{0}:FormUpgrade>")]
    public class FormUpgrade : WebControl
    {
        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Appearance")]
        [DefaultValue("")]
        [Localizable(true)]

        public Label aLabel = new Label();
        public TextBox aField = new TextBox();
        public RegularExpressionValidator regexvalid = new RegularExpressionValidator();

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            regexvalid.ID = ID + "_validator";

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ID))
            {
                aField.ID = ID+"_box";
                aLabel.ID = ID + "_label";
                aLabel.AssociatedControlID = aLabel.ID;
            }

            //aField.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
            // aLabel.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");


            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(required))
            {
                aField.Attributes.Add("required", required);
                if (required.Equals("required"))
                {
                    aLabel.Attributes.Add("class", "required");
                }
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            {
                aField.Attributes.Add("name", name);
                aLabel.Text = name;
            }
            else
            {
                aLabel.Text = ID;
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(placeholder))
            {
                aField.Attributes.Add("placeholder", placeholder);
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(role))
            {
                aField.Attributes.Add("role", role);
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(maxlength))
            {
                aField.Attributes.Add("maxlength", maxlength);
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(placeholder))
            {
                aField.Attributes.Add("placeholder", placeholder);
            }

            aLabel.Attributes.Add("for", ID+"_box");

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(type))
            {
                aField.Attributes.Add("type", type);
            }

            //if (type.Equals("date"))
            //{
            //    aField.Attributes.Add("class", "hasDatepicker");
            //}

            if(type.Equals("textarea"))
            {
                aField.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
            }

            if (type.Equals("password"))
            {
                aField.TextMode = TextBoxMode.Password;
            }

            aLabel.Text = name;

            this.Controls.Add(this.aLabel);
            this.Controls.Add(this.aField);

            if(type.Equals("email"))
            {
                regexvalid.ValidationExpression = "[a-zA-Z0-9]+([-+.][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9]+([-.][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*.[a-zA-Z0-9]+([-.][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*";
                regexvalid.ControlToValidate = ID+"_box";
                regexvalid.ErrorMessage = "Not a valid email address <br>";

                this.Controls.Add(regexvalid);
            }
            else if (type.Equals("url"))
            {
                regexvalid.ValidationExpression = "http(s)?://([a-zA-Z0-9-]+.)+[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(/[a-zA-Z0-9- ./?%&=]*)?";
                regexvalid.ControlToValidate = ID + "_box";
                regexvalid.ErrorMessage = "Not a valid URL<br>";

                this.Controls.Add(regexvalid);
            } 
            else if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ValidationExpression))
            {
                  regexvalid.ControlToValidate = ID + "_box";
                  regexvalid.ValidationExpression = ValidationExpression;

                  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ValidationErrorMessage))
                  {
                      regexvalid.ErrorMessage = ValidationErrorMessage + "<br>";
                  }

                  this.Controls.Add(regexvalid);
           }

            base.OnInit(e);
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get
            {
                String s = (String)ViewState["Text"];
                return ((s == null) ? "[" + this.ID + "]" : s);
            }
            set
            {
                ViewState["Text"] = value;
            }
        }

        public string type
        {
            get
            {
                String s = (String)ViewState["type"];
                return ((s == null) ? "[" + this.ID + "]" : s);
            }
            set
            {
                ViewState["type"] = value;
            }
        }

        public string name
        {
            get
            {
                String s = (String)ViewState["name"];
                return ((s == null) ? "" : s);
            }
            set
            {
                ViewState["name"] = value;
            }
        }

        public string required
        {
            get
            {
                String s = (String)ViewState["required"];
                return ((s == null) ? "" : s);
            }
            set
            {
                ViewState["required"] = value;
            }
        }

        public string role
        {
            get
            {
                String s = (String)ViewState["role"];
                return ((s == null) ? "" : s);
            }
            set
            {
                ViewState["role"] = value;
            }
        }

        public string ValidationExpression
        {
            get
            {
                String s = (String)ViewState["ValidationExpression"];
                return ((s == null) ? "" : s);
            }
            set
            {
                ViewState["ValidationExpression"] = value;
            }
        }

        public string ValidationErrorMessage
        {
            get
            {
                String s = (String)ViewState["ValidationErrorMessage"];
                return ((s == null) ? "" : s);
            }
            set
            {
                ViewState["ValidationErrorMessage"] = value;
            }
        }

        public string placeholder
        {
            get
            {
                String s = (String)ViewState["placeholder"];
                return ((s == null) ? "" : s);
            }
            set
            {
                ViewState["placeholder"] = value;
            }
        }

        public string Display
        {
            get
            {
                String s = (String)ViewState["Display"];
                return ((s == null) ? "" : s);
            }
            set
            {
                ViewState["Display"] = value;
            }
        }

        public string maxlength
        {
            get
            {
                String s = (String)ViewState["maxlength"];
                return ((s == null) ? "" : s);
            }
            set
            {
                ViewState["maxlength"] = value;
            }
        }

        public string Value
        {
            get
            {
                String s = (String)ViewState["Value"];
                return ((s == null) ? "" : s);
            }
            set
            {
                ViewState["Value"] = value;
            }
        }

        public override void RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
        }

        public override void RenderEndTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I did not know about an official accept feature before.

Comment: It's right in the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem could be right here:

```
public string Text 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        String s = (String)ViewState["Text"]; 
        return ((s == null) ? "[" + this.ID + "]" : s); 
    } 

    set 
    { 
        ViewState["Text"] = value; 
    } 
}
```

I'm thinking that `s` is returning null, and returning ID instead. Try just returning an empty string if `Text` is null.

Comment: I'm confused, the only time I call text is when I'm invoking aLabel.Text, not fname.Text.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused. What's the problem, exactly? It's kind of tough to conceptualize your control without any context, but I think this might be happening because you're setting the value in `OnInit`, before ViewState has reloaded. What is your `Text` property being used for?

Comment: the text property comes by default when you create a control in Visual Studio. I haven't used it for anything and in my oninit file, I never call the instance variable 'Text'. I'm using one control to create a label, input, and regular expression validator. I want the name component in my custom control to determine what text the label displays. Unfortunately, what the label displays is determined by the ID variable instead of the name variable.